# Where can I find free single-day charts for the S&P 500?

Tags: historical-data, intraday, charts, historical

I'm trying to find free historical charts of the S&P 500.  I don't need the raw data, I just need to access a simple chart showing the movement of the index over the course of the day (for an arbitrary day).  It would be fantastic if the source could generate charts for several years back, but even just a few months back would be acceptable.

Where can I find charts like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want the charts, you can get this on the TD Ameritrade platform.  You do need a funded account, so it is not exactly "free" but there aren't any fees associated with it.

In their desktop client, you can select "On Demand" mode.  This gives you the ability to rewind to earlier points in history for sim trading purposes.  Just rewind back to a date shortly after the day you want to examine.

For instance, I just went to January, 2010 and the 1-minute data for SPX (their symbol for the index) came up fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! Any idea how much cash is need to outlay to "fund" the account? (Ballpark)

Comment: *I'd need to outlay

Comment: Supposedly you can open an individual account for \$50

My account was a margin account with a minimum of \$2000 but I am pretty sure you get the same tools.

Comment: I've been searching and searching in the Trade Architect program, but I can't find "On Demand" mode anywhere.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Where specifically do I click?  (Everything I'm seeing is for real-time data)

Comment: It's the thinkorswim platform, you can get it here

https://www.tdameritrade.com/tools-and-platforms/thinkorswim/features.page

Answer (score 0):

If you are a programmer, you could just download the CSV data from yahoo finance or google or any other source. As you are not expecting real time data, and you seem to be more interested in long term data, it should be very easy.

once you have the CSV data, you could generate the required reports in excel, as you like, which is just a 1 min configuration in CSV files.